# Call a service function inside bootbox callback

Tags: angular, bootbox

```
voidfn = () => {
      bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to continue", function (result, apiService) {
          if (result == true) {

              let response = this.apiService.getVoid(systemId, orderId).subscribe(
                  success => {
                      this.spinner = false;
                      this.toastr.success("Success");
                  }, error => {
                      this.spinner = false;                

                  }
              );
          }
      });

  }
```

In this code, I couldn't access the `getVoid()` method since `apiservice` is not available inside `bootbox` call.

Is there a way to do this. Kindly suggest..

Comment: add more code and what is bootbox?

Comment: Bootbox is kind of alert box which is available from a plugin

Comment: if you add more data means how and where service is initialized and added to the component/module then we would help you with more accuracy.

Comment: Service is imported as normal import { ApiService } from '../../../service/API Service/APIService'; and injected in constructor     constructor( private apiService: ApiService)

Comment: check whether you have added service on 2 instances i.e. on 2 modules which are imported as a child parent?

Comment: sry couldn`t understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have resolved above problem with arrow function

```
voidfn = () => {
      bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to continue", (result)=> {
          if (result == true) {

              let response = this.apiService.getVoid(systemId, orderId).subscribe(
                  success => {
                      this.spinner = false;
                      this.toastr.success("Success");
                  }, error => {
                      this.spinner = false;                

                  }
              );
          }
      });
```